# Run Visual Studio project in VS Code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

How can I run a VS project in VS Code?

When I type `dotnet run` in the terminal I get:

> Couldn't find a project to run. Ensure a project exists

Comment: `dotnet run` operates on `.csproj` files, which VS Code doesn't support by default.

Comment: Is there something I can do? Perhaps an extension or something?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to it is unable to find a project to run. So go to directory where you have .csproj file and then try to execute dotnet run it will eventually result into success.

Answer (score 0):

go to project directory where there is `.csproj` file

enter:

```
dotnet run
```